# StartForeground for IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, foreground-service

I have an `IntentService` and I want to make it sticky with an ongoing notification. The problem is that the notification appears and then disappears immediately. The service continues to run. How should I use `startForeground()` in an `IntentService`?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.marker, "Notification service is running",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "App",
            "Notification service is running", pendingIntent);
    notification.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(1337, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String id = intent.getStringExtra(ID);
    WebSocketConnectConfig config = new WebSocketConnectConfig();
    try {
        config.setUrl(new URI("ws://" + App.NET_ADDRESS
                + "/App/socket?id="+id));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ws = SimpleSocketFactory.create(config, this);
    ws.open();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should not be an `IntentService`. As written, your `IntentService` will live for a millisecond or so. Once `onHandleIntent()` returns, the service is destroyed. This should be a regular `Service`, where you fork your own thread and manage the lifetime of the thread and the service.

The reason your `Notification` is going away immediately is because the service is going away immediately.

Comment: Downvoted because: It's likely an incorrect answer. Excerpt from IntentService docs: "All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- *they may take as long as necessary* (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time." Nothing said about millisecond or so. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: As written, this `IntentService` will live for a millisecond or so, for the simple reason that the code in `onHandleIntent()` will only take a millisecond or so to run.

Comment: @GregoryK Actually the answer is correct because `onHandleIntent` method doesn't contains any thread blocking code to prevent `IntentService` destroying.

Comment: this answer is not correct, as per documentation:  `This method may take several seconds to complete, so it should only be called from a worker thread.`

Answer (score 6):

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for `IntentService` states:

> ...the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a
>   worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

So, I suppose the problem, is that your service is out of work after `onHandleIntent()` is finished. Hence, service stops itself and notification is dissmissed. So, concept of IntentService is probably not the best case for your task.

---

As question's title is "StartForeground for IntentService", I would like to clarify some things:

It's really simple to make your IntentService to run in foreground (see code below), but for sure you need to consider several things:

- Don't run service in foreground if it takes a few seconds only - that might bug your users. Imagine you run short tasks periodically - that will cause notification to appear and disappear - uhhhh*
- You might need to make your service capable to keep device awake (but that's another story, which is covered pretty well on stackoverflow)*
- If you queued up multiple Intents to your IntentService the below code will end up showing/hiding notification. (So there might be better solution for your case - as @CommonsWare suggests to extend Service and do everything yourself, however would like to mention - there is nothing in javadoc for IntentService saying that it works only a few seconds - it works as long as it has to do something.)

---

```
public class ForegroundService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "FrgrndSrv";

    public ForegroundService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_foreground_service)
                .setTicker("Your Ticker") // use something from something from R.string
                .setContentTitle("Your content title") // use something from something from
                .setContentText("Your content text") // use something from something from
                .setProgress(0, 0, true); // display indeterminate progress

        startForeground(1, builder.build());
        try {
            doIntesiveWork();
        } finally {
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    }

    protected void doIntesiveWork() {
        // Below should be your logic that takes lots of time
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A general rule for computer programming is: never make assumptions about a resource that something else acquired on your behalf. You did not create the background thread used by `IntentService`; hence, you should not make any assumptions about how long you can safely use it. We ran into this very problem with `AsyncTask`, where Google changed the rules for `execute()`, limiting you to a single thread across all tasks. If you want to hold a thread for longer than a brief period, create your own thread. Downvoting for recommending embarrassing programming practices.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see your point and understand it. That makes sense. Actually, I was a bit disagree about the statement "As written, your IntentService will live for a millisecond or so." I'm not trying to make assumptions, API java says: "IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work."