# How to implement IntentService as foreground service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to use IntentService as foreground service, but I cannot find sample code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/intent-services

Can anyone provide sample code?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understand-intentservice-in-xamarin-with-visual-studio-2015/ you can refer to this link.

Comment: This question may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964031/using-startforeground-with-an-intent-service