# startForeground fails to show my notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service, proximity, proximitysensor

`startForeground()` fails to show the notification below, which is meant to keep a service that monitors the changes in the Proximity sensor alive. There's no error in the logcat.

This's where I start the service

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ProximityService.class);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        ctx.startForegroundService(intent);
    } else {
        ctx.startService(intent);
    }
```

ProximityService class

```
public class ProximityService extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground(){

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.xxxxxx";
    String channelName = "Background Proximity Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent aIntent, int aFlags, int aStartId){
    super.onStartCommand(aIntent, aFlags, aStartId);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());


    return START_STICKY;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {

        if (event.values[0] < event.sensor.getMaximumRange()) {
            // near
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // far
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public ProximityService() {
    super("Proximity Service");
}


protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    SensorManager m_sensor_manager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor m_prox = m_sensor_manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

    m_sensor_manager.registerListener(this, m_prox, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ProximityService"/>
```

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Comment: Try to change `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE` to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW`

Comment: @Zain I set it to IMPORTANCE_HIGH and it doesn't show. I'm gonna update the code here in the question. Any other suggestions

Comment: Isn't it shown on certain API levels?

Comment: @Zain I have only one device to test on which's powered by Android 10.

Comment: Try to replace `startForeground(1, notification);` with `startForeground(1, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST);`.. Not totally true but a trial to limit the issue

Comment: @Zain I just tried it, and same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the customized foreground service is extending from the [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) instead of the [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) class; and when the `onHandleIntent()` get completed, the `IntentService` will automatically stop, and therefore no notification comes up. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964031/using-startforeground-with-an-intent-service) for complete understanding.

So, you need to extend from the `Service` class, and override `onBind()` accordingly. So, append it to your class:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Also notice that the `IntentService` is deprecated as of API level 30, and replaced by `WorkManager` or `JobIntentService`

Comment: Thank you so much Zain for your help and such comprehensive answer, really appreciated and it solved my problem :)